# How to count average grade with String[][] given and String[][] return expected

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

I have a 2d array given as an input, where all items are strings. Data is in format - name, grade. I'm supposed to write a method taking this array as an input and return String[][] showing distinct name and an average of grades. All that using streams.

```
{"Ann", "5"},
{"Tom", "6"},
{"Kate", "3"},
{"Albert", "2"},
{"Ann", "3"},
{"Tom", "1"},
{"Tom", "4"},
{"John", "2"}
```

What I achieved so far is to print this output:

```
Ann=4.0
Tom=3.6666666666666665
Kate=3.0
John=2.0
Albert=2.0
```

with this code:

```
Arrays.stream(input)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0], Collectors.averagingDouble(a -> Double.parseDouble(a[1]))))
        .entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

(I'm using system.out just to check the output since I'm stuck.)

The output needs to be sorted by a name, grades formatted to two decimal places with DecimalFormat. Empty array should be returned in case of passing null input (I suppose it might be a hint about using optionals).

I looked for different solutions to give me a clue, but I'm stuck totally. I'm not even sure if my output is a 2d array. And it's definitely noto sorted nor formatted. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After collecting into `Map` you can stream and convert each entry into `String[]` array by sorting on name and then use `toArray` to convert into 2d array

```
String[][] output = Arrays.stream(input)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0], Collectors.averagingDouble(a -> Double.parseDouble(a[1]))))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .map(ar -> new String[] { ar.getKey(), String.format( "%.2f", ar.getValue()) })
            .toArray(String[][]::new);

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(output));  //[[Ann, 5.00], [Tom, 3.50]]
```

If input array can be null then you have check before streaming the array using ternary operator

```
input = Objects.nonNull(input) ? input : new String[][] {{}};
```

You can also check inner array objects by using filter

```
Arrays.stream(input)
            .filter(inArray->Objects.nonNull(inArray) && inArray.length==2)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0], Collectors.averagingDouble(a -> Double.parseDouble(a[1]))))
```

Comment: Since it's an assignment I'd put hints here with a link to the solution so he can try to figure it out before giving it away

Comment: Thanks i never thought it is an assignment @MartijnWoudstra